# Excepción mapeo OneToMany Spring Boot v2.2.10

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

**Editado (7/10/20 18.55):** Ahora está a saltar el siguiente error con respecto a la relación Empleado-Usuario.

**Spring Boot Console**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.crmiguez.inventario_aixina.entities.Empleado.usuariosSet[com.crmiguez.xxxxxxxxxx.entities.Usuario]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1331) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:868) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:793) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1684) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1652) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:900) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:931) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 105 common frames omitted
```

**Usuario.class**

```
    public class Usuario implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "idusuarios")
        private Long idusuarios;
    
        @JoinColumn(name = "empleado_usuario", referencedColumnName = "idempleados")
        @ManyToOne
        private Empleado empleado_usuario;
    
        @Column(name = "nombre_usuario")
        private String nombre_usuario;
    
        @Column(name = "email_usuario")
        private String email_usuario;
    
        @Column(name = "password_usuario")
        private String password_usuario;
    
        @Column(name = "ultima_conexion")
        private String ultima_conexion;
    
        @Column(name = "fecha_alta_usuario")
        private String fecha_alta_usuario;
    
        @Column(name = "fecha_baja_usuario")
        private String fecha_baja_usuario;
    
        @Column(name="es_administrador")
        @ColumnDefault(value = "0")
        private byte es_administrador;
    
        public Usuario() {
        }
//Getters and setters
}
```

**Tabla Usuario en MySQL**

[image: Tabla Usuario MySQL]

---

Al arrancar el Spring Boot, salta una excepción de mapeo OneToMany, entre Empleado y Articulo. Lo que pretendo es integrar tanto ManyToOne como OneToMany entre las dos.

**Spring Boot Console**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.crmiguez.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entities.Empleado.articulos in com.crmiguez.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entities.Articulo.empleadosSet
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:842) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:793) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1684) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1652) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:900) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:931) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
```

Las clases las tengo de la siguiente forma.

**Articulo.class** (Se guardarán los diferentes artículos)

```
@Entity(name = "articulos")
@Table
public class Articulo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "idarticulos")
    private Long idarticulos;

    @Column(name = "nombre_articulo")
    private String nombre_articulo;

    @Column(name = "fecha_alta_articulo")
    private String fecha_alta_articulo;

    @Column(name = "fecha_baja_articulo")
    private String fecha_baja_articulo;

    @Column(name = "numero_pegatina")
    private String numero_pegatina;

    @JoinColumn(name = "tipo_inmueble", referencedColumnName = "idtipo_inmueble", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    private TipoInmueble tipo_inmueble;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="articulos")
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Empleado> empleadosSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="articulos")
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Inmueble> inmueblesSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="articulos")
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Inventario> inventariosSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="articulos")
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Movimiento> movimientosSet = new HashSet<>();


    public Articulo() {
    }
    //Getters and setters

}
```

**Empleado.class** (Se guardarán la información de los empleados de la compañía)

```
@Entity(name = "empleados")
@Table
public class Empleado implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "idempleados")
    private Long idempleados;

    @Column(name = "nombre_empleado")
    private String nombre_empleado;

    @Column(name = "apellidos_empleado")
    private String apellidos_empleado;

    @Column(name = "dni_empleado")
    private String dni_empleado;

    @JoinColumn(name = "departamento_empleado", referencedColumnName = "iddepartamentos")
    @ManyToOne
    private Departamento departamento;

    @JoinColumn(name = "departamento_ubicacion", referencedColumnName = "iddepartamento")
    @JoinColumn(name = "ubicacion_empleado", referencedColumnName = "idubicacion")
    @ManyToOne
    private UbicacionPlanta ubicacionPlanta;

    @JoinColumn(name = "responsable_empleado", referencedColumnName = "idempleados")
    @ManyToOne
    private Empleado responsable_empleado;

    @JoinColumn(name = "articulo_empleado", referencedColumnName = "idarticulos")
    @ManyToOne
    private Articulo articulo_empleado;

    @JoinColumn(name = "inmueble_empleado", referencedColumnName = "idinmuebles")
    @ManyToOne
    private Inmueble inmueble_empleado;

    @Column(name = "fecha_alta_empleado")
    private String fecha_alta_empleado;

    @Column(name = "fecha_baja_empleado")
    private String fecha_baja_empleado;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "empleados")
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    Set<Usuario> usuariosSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="empleados")
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Inventario> inventariosSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "empleados")
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Movimiento> movimientosEmpSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "responsable_emp")
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Empleado> empleadosSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "responsable_emp")
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Movimiento> movimientosResponsableSet = new HashSet<>();

    public Empleado() {
    }
//Getters and setters
}
```

Las tablas en MySQL se muestran en las siguientes imágenes:

[image: Tabla Articulo MySQL]

[image: Tabla Empleado MySQL]

Alguna forma de mapear mejor estas entidades, por favor? Cómo tengo que indicarle a Hibernate que el mapeo tiene que ser una forma u otra?

Muchas gracias! :)

Comment: Prueba cambiar `mappedBy="articulos"` a `mappedBy="articulo"` segun recuerdo es el nombre de la entidad no de la tabla la que debes colocar.

Comment: Yo cuando me hago un lio con las anotaciones, lo que hago es desde netbeans darle a new -> other -> persistence -> entity classes from database, de esa forma me genera las clases de entidad con sus anotaciones automáticamente.

Comment: @ordago Y desde Intellij IDEA?

Comment: @crmiguez mira a ver si te vale esto, no es exactamente un tutorial pero dice unos pasos para hacerlo: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000751864-Generate-Persistence-Mapping-by-Database-Schema-Detail-settings-for-Entity-Class

Comment: @ordago El enlace ha sido de gran ayuda. Gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras varias pruebas, las clases quedan de la siguiente forma:

**Articulo.class**

```
@Entity(name = "articulo")
@Table
public class Articulo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "idarticulos")
    private Long idarticulos;

    @Column(name = "nombre_articulo")
    private String nombre_articulo;

    @Column(name = "fecha_alta_articulo")
    private String fecha_alta_articulo;

    @Column(name = "fecha_baja_articulo")
    private String fecha_baja_articulo;

    @Column(name = "numero_pegatina")
    private String numero_pegatina;

    @JoinColumn(name = "tipo_inmueble", referencedColumnName = "idtipo_inmueble", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    private TipoInmueble tipo_inmueble;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="articulos")
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Empleado> empleadosSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="articulo")
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Inmueble> inmueblesSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="articulo")
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Inventario> inventariosSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="articulo")
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Movimiento> movimientosSet = new HashSet<>();


    public Articulo() {
    }
    //Getters and setters

}
```

**Empleado.class**

```
@Entity(name = "empleado")
@Table
public class Empleado implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "idempleados")
    private Long idempleados;

    @Column(name = "nombre_empleado")
    private String nombre_empleado;

    @Column(name = "apellidos_empleado")
    private String apellidos_empleado;

    @Column(name = "dni_empleado")
    private String dni_empleado;

    @JoinColumn(name = "departamento_empleado", referencedColumnName = "iddepartamentos")
    @ManyToOne
    private Departamento departamento;

    @JoinColumn(name = "ubicacion_empleado", referencedColumnName = "idubicacion")
    @ManyToOne
    private UbicacionPlanta ubicacionPlanta;

    @JoinColumn(name = "responsable_empleado", referencedColumnName = "idempleados")
    @ManyToOne
    private Empleado responsable_empleado;

    @JoinColumn(name = "articulo_empleado", referencedColumnName = "idarticulos")
    @ManyToOne
    private Articulo articulo_empleado;

    @JoinColumn(name = "inmueble_empleado", referencedColumnName = "idinmuebles")
    @ManyToOne
    private Inmueble inmueble_empleado;

    @Column(name = "fecha_alta_empleado")
    private String fecha_alta_empleado;

    @Column(name = "fecha_baja_empleado")
    private String fecha_baja_empleado;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "empleado")
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    Set<Usuario> usuariosSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="empleado")
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Inventario> inventariosSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "empleado")
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Movimiento> movimientosEmpSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "responsable_emp")
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Empleado> empleadosSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "responsable_emp")
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Movimiento> movimientosResponsableSet = new HashSet<>();

    public Empleado() {
    }
//Getters and setters
}
```

**Usuario.class**

```
@Entity(name = "usuario")
@Table
public class Usuario implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "idusuarios")
    private Long idusuarios;

    @JoinColumn(name = "empleado_usuario", referencedColumnName = "idempleados")
    @ManyToOne
    private Empleado empleado_usuario;

    @Column(name = "nombre_usuario")
    private String nombre_usuario;

    @Column(name = "email_usuario")
    private String email_usuario;

    @Column(name = "password_usuario")
    private String password_usuario;

    @Column(name = "ultima_conexion")
    private String ultima_conexion;

    @Column(name = "fecha_alta_usuario")
    private String fecha_alta_usuario;

    @Column(name = "fecha_baja_usuario")
    private String fecha_baja_usuario;

    @Column(name="es_administrador")
    @ColumnDefault(value = "0")
    private byte es_administrador;

    public Usuario() {
    }
        //Getters and setters
    }
```